# Python3.8.2 Compile Cython Extensions Error - warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, cython

Running any program in debugger mode in PyCharm CE I get a `Python Debugger Extensions Available` pop up.

[image]

When I try to click install I get a massive error message that starts with:

> None-zero exit code (1):
>   _pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython.c:23387:72: warning: 'tp_print' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
>   __pyx_type_14_pydevd_bundle_13pydevd_cython_PyDBAdditionalThreadInfo.tp_print
>   = 0;
>   ^

I only get this while using Python3.8.2

Full error message doesn't fit my screen and is not scrollable but here it is:

[image]

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug in a specific proprietary software package and belongs on their bug tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the cython extension was built with a cython not quite compatible with python 3.8: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/changes.html#id8

What you can do is either:

- use python 3.7
- not install the cython extension
- find or rebuid pydevd with a more recent version, or possibly update your IDE

Either way this is an issue with PyCharm CE and should be reported on Jetbrains' bug tracker, not here.

Comment: Ya, I had PyCharm v2017.3.7 and updating to v2019.3.4 solved the issue.